# Check jshint errors before npm run build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, jshint

I have setup webpack using npm. I installed jshint using `npm install jshint --save-dev`.

Now if I run command `jshint assets/js/index.js` i get errors.

I want to check the errors on `npm run build`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your build script in the package.json in the way to run lint and then if it successful run build. See example

```
{
...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm run lint && your_build_command",
    "lint": "jshint assets/js/index.js"
   }
...
}
```

Comment: what if i add jshint command directly in build script like this:-

`{
...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "jshint assets/js/index.js && your_build_command",
   }
...
}`

Comment: I can do that. But in my case, you will be able to lint your code without building it if you need it by run npm run lint

Comment: Initially i had done like my above comment but it was not showing errors. Your above code worked well. Thanks